# CSS select a class containing plus sign "+"

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I select an element by class name containing a plus sign `+`?

E.g.

```css
.frme_150+1 {background-position: 150px 1px;}
```

The plus value is changed by using JavaScript, is this possible to use `+` character in selector name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd need to **[escape](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)** the plus sign as it has a [special meaning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) in CSS, by using a leading backslash `\` [as follows](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0frme_150+1):

```css
.frme_150\+1 {
    background-position: 150px 1px;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/965Jt/1/)**.

Or escape the `'+'` to [`'\2b '`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/965Jt/3/) or [`'\00002b'`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/965Jt/2/) (six hexadecimal digits)

Also, you can achieve this by using **[CSS Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)**:

```css
[class="frme_150+1"] { background-position:150px 1px; }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/965Jt/)**.

Comment: Yes in most cases, Including IE7+