# How can I select a div by id that is nested within another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now I have some html that looks like this once rendered.

```
<div id="MyPartial">
    <div id="div+1"></div>
    <div id="div+2"></div>
    <div id="div+3"></div>
</div>
```

All of the div's inside of the MyPartial div are dynamic. so there could be 3, or there could be none.  I am trying to remove them one at a time via there ID.

```
$("#div+" + Id).remove()
```

this didn't work so i tried this

```
$("#MyPartial").children().select("#div+" + Id).remove();
```

This removes the entire 'MyPartial' div.

What am I missing?  The first statement has always worked fine for me in the past but it seems like the nesting is messing things up now.

Edit: the plus sign was messing me up. I changed it to an underscore and it works fine.  thanks everyone.

Comment: Try `$("#div\\+" + Id)`. You're selecting using an ID, so you need the number sign identifier (`#`).

Comment: Given all IDs on the page should be unique why can't you just do $('#div+' + id)?

Comment: I would avoid '+' char in your id. The char '_' would be better.

Comment: You might also need to escape the `+` like `$("#div\\+" + Id).remove()`. `+` can be parsed as a CSS selector and will select the next element

Comment: @Flea777 Id names can be anything these days.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, of course, but for example you'll need to escape it in a selector or a regex.

Comment: I had a bit of a typo in my initial post.  let me see if i can get this to work real quick and get back to you all. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a plus (+) sign in your id! It is a selector (see http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)

If you really want to use a plus in your is, you should escape it (see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

example:

```
$('#div\\+1').remove();
```

Comment: I was wondering about that plus for way too long...  I figured it was probably some sort of escape character. I changed it to an underscore and it works fine now.  thanks for the help.  jQuery is still weird/new to me and the syntax of it is still tough.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` is not allowed in class- and id-attributes. In CSS `+` has a selector-meaning. It means: select the next neighbour-element.

Maybe that's why jQuery can't select your elements. Try to give your ids other names like `div_1`, 'div_2`,...

Afterwards you can select an element by its id like so `$('#div_1')`.

Since ids should be unique within the whole document this selector should be the same as `$('#myPartial #div_1')`

Comment: The first sentence is simply not true.

Comment: @MrLister Sorry it's called "adjacent"-selector in english - not neighbour-selector: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean Or what do you exactly mean about my sentence?

Comment: Okay I just found another proof, that you're right. My bad then...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378209/css-select-a-class-containing-plus-sign

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#div+" + Id).remove()`.

That being said, ids are unique, always. Or they should. So, there is no need to find within the parent. See

> 7.5.2 Element identifiers: the id and class attributes
>   Attribute definitions
>   id = name [CS]
>   This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

See [the refference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Edit: Based on comments, it is right to say this does not work and this work

> $('#div\\+1').remove();

Again, that being said, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html), although the plus sign is not forbidden to my understanding, jquery has issues with it. If possible, I would remove the plus sign, if not, then use the escaped version.

Comment: You are right, I was surprised it doesn't though. The escaped version seems to work  but anyway I would think it's easier to write the code without the plus sign.

Comment: Yes it's better to rely on valid html and class-names

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#MyPartial #div+" + Id).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs should ALWAYS BE DISTINCT ...

Try making them classes, then you can use `$("#MyPartial .div+" + Id)`

If `div+1` is an id twice, only the first one can be accessed.

If the IDs are truly unique (DISTINCT), then just use `$("#div+1")`

Comment: The OPs users *are* unique, they are simply using the selector incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

ID should always be unique in the page, you don't have to worry about its parent

```
$("#div+" + Id).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issueis the jquery will escape the plus sign..
what if you do something like

$(document.getElementById(Id)).remove()

Comment: what should be `Id` be ? This make no sense to me

Comment: well, it's a variable.. the same as he used in his code.. it makes sense i think

Answer (score 0):

There a tw0 problems with your code.  1. You forgot to put the id selector "#" in front of your div selector.  2. An `id` cannot contain a "+".  I replaced it with a "-" and it works just fine.

```js
var Id = "1";
$("#div-" + Id).remove()
```

```css
div {
  
  background: blue;
  
  }

div > div {
  
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyPartial">
    <div id="div-1">1</div>
    <div id="div-2">2</div>
    <div id="div-3">3</div>
</div>
```